# How to Loop Through Rows of Checkboxes in an HTML Table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I have a question about how to loop through checkboxes in a table.

What I want to do is create two checkboxes per row in a table along with a pulldown menu.  I will run a conditional in javascript based upon if both checkboxes per row are selected.  If both checkboxes in a row are selected along with a pulldown menu option, I will run a conditional.

So I want to loop through each row of the table checking if both checkboxes are selected.  I think another way to do this is to maybe use divs and classes. How do I do this?

My sample code below is not in a table, but it is what I have so far just to get the checkboxes and pulldown menu to work.

```
<html>
<div class="container">
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Apple">Apple<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="BananaValue">Banana<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Carrot">Carrot<br>

<form>
  Select your favorite fruit:
  <select id="mySelect" /*onchange="run();"*/>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>

<input type="submit" onclick="run()" />

<script>
function run() {
    var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
    var str = '';

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (checks[i].checked === true) {
            str += checks[i].value + " ";
        }
    }

    alert(str);
}
</script>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be good if you could create a fiddle or codepen. Would be easier for people to answer.

Comment: Anyone can just copy and paste the code into a text editor and save as html.  Sorry I didn't put it in an html table format like I should have.  I am frustrated with it.

Comment: No problem, but it's just easier for people to help out and motivate people to actually try to solve your problem. A lot of people might just ignore this because of the extra work involved in replicating the example.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Without the table format, which of the 3 (not 2) checkboxes are to constitute a row?  You only have one drop down displayed, so are the others the same for each row?  Can you define the problem better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
The code is updated to work with the info from your comment. It will only run when the one button is clicked

Orig:
I commented out (but kept) the code for this in case you need it later. Here's a working example of what you want (I think).  In the window.load listener, we first loop through all the rows to see if any are ready to run the conditional on. Then we set up the `change` listener on each form element in the table. The listener listens for a change event, then runs our row check.

```js
/*
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.theTable tr').forEach(row => checkRow(row))

  document.querySelectorAll('.theTable td input[type=checkbox], .theTable td select').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', e => checkRow(e.target.closest('tr')))
  })
})
*/

function run() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.theTable tr').forEach((row, i) => {
    let allChecked = row.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').length === row.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length

    if (allChecked && row.querySelectorAll('select option:checked').length > 0 && row.querySelector('select option:checked').value !== '') {
      console.log('run conditional on row index ', i)
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="run()" />

<table class='theTable'>
  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Apple" checked>Apple </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="BananaValue" checked>Banana </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Carrot" checked>Carrot </label>
      </td>
      <td>

        Select your favorite fruit:
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="apple">apple</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option selected value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Apple">Apple </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="BananaValue">Banana </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Carrot">Carrot </label>
      </td>
      <td>

        Select your favorite fruit:
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="apple">apple</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
        </select>
      </td>

    </form>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Wow.  That was fast.  The table format is what I had intended.  It took me a while just to figure out this sample code.  I wanted the conditional check to be done when the submit button is clicked.  I am going to have one submit button at the top outside of the table.

Comment: That answers my question about more than one checkbox in a row.  You hit the nail on the head.  Thanks very much Kinglish.  I may contact you with more questions.

Comment: Great. If this answered your question, consider marking it as the solution by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks

Comment: How would I run a conditional to check if the first checkbox in the first column of each row was empty Kinglish?

Answer (score 0):

I read the initial conditions of the problem a little differently,
therefore this may not suffice as the acceptable answer.

1. I read that 2 and only 2 vegetable choices were allowed per row.
2. The select choice of fruit was to be added only if #1 condition fulfilled.

With that in mind, here is my solution submission.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<!-- From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68329725/how-to-loop-through-rows-of-checkboxes-in-an-html-table-in-javascript -->
<title> Table Food Choices </title>
<!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" media="screen" -->
<style>

</style>

<body>
<form>
 <h3> From each row: </h3>
 <table id="tbl">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Select 2 vetables</th>
    <th>And your favorite fruit:</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td> <label><input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Beans">Green Bean</label></td>
    <td> <label><input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Corn">Corn</label></td>
    <td> <label><input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Carrot">Carrot</label></td>
    <th>
     <select>
      <option value="apple">Apple</option>
      <option value="banana">Banana</option>
      <option value="grape">Grape</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      <option value="peach">Peach</option>
      <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
      <option value="tangerine">Tangerine</option>
     </select>
    </th>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td> <label><input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Beans">Green Bean</label></td>
    <td> <label><input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Corn">Corn</label></td>
    <td> <label><input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Carrot">Carrot</label></td>
    <th>
     <select>
      <option value="apple">Apple</option>
      <option value="banana">Banana</option>
      <option value="grape">Grape</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      <option value="peach">Peach</option>
      <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
      <option value="tangerine">Tangerine</option>
     </select>
    </th>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td> <label><input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Beans">Green Bean</label></td>
    <td> <label><input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Corn">Corn</label></td>
    <td> <label><input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Carrot">Carrot</label></td>
    <th>
     <select>
      <option value="apple">Apple</option>
      <option value="banana">Banana</option>
      <option value="grape">Grape</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      <option value="peach">Peach</option>
      <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
      <option value="tangerine">Tangerine</option>
     </select>
    </th>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>

<input id="picks" type="submit" value="Submit choices">
<br>
Choices
<pre id='choices'></pre>

<script>
function run(){
  var
      tblRows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr'),
      checks = document.querySelectorAll('.checks'),
      selects = document.querySelectorAll('select'),
      strs = [];                                       // console.log(tblRows.length, checks.length, selects.length);

  for (r = 0; r < tblRows.length; r++) {
    let cbCount = 0, tstr = '';
    for (cb=0; cb < 3; cb++) {
      if ( checks[(r*3)+cb].checked ) {
        cbCount++;
        tstr += checks[(r*3)+cb].value + ' ';
      }
    }
    if ( cbCount == 2 ) { strs.push(tstr + " " + selects[r].value); }  // accept only 2 checkbox with 1 select values
  }     
  document.getElementById('choices').textContent = strs.join('\n');
}
function init() {
  document.getElementById('picks').addEventListener('click', run);
}
init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```